# Can a shader rotate shapes to face camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a scene where balls appear in 3D space. Triangle balls spend a lot of resources. So I did this using 2d surfaces (quad) with a ball texture. But now I need to adjust the direction of the shape every time the camera moves. I do this using position transformation and the LookAt method. The question is can I optimize this? If it is possible to rotate the shapes with shader, this will greatly help.

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;

public class WorldSurf : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject[] matrix;

    int xSize =  20;
    int ySize =  20;
    int zSize =  20;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        matrix = new GameObject[xSize * ySize * zSize];

        //var shader = Shader.Find("Legacy Shaders/Diffuse");
        var shader = Shader.Find("Sprites/Default");
        //var texture = Resources.Load<Texture>("Textures/Ball_01");

        var i = 0;

        for (var x = 0f; x < xSize; ++x)
        {
            for (var y = 0f; y < ySize; ++y)
            {
                for (var z = 0f; z < zSize; ++z)
                {
                    var texture = Resources.Load<Texture>("Textures/Ball_" + ((int)Random.Range(0, 15)).ToString("00"));

                    matrix[i++] = CreateQuad(x * 3, y * 3, z * 3, shader, texture);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static GameObject CreateQuad(float x, float y, float z, Shader shader, Texture texture)
    {
        var quad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);

        quad.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        quad.transform.forward = Camera.main.transform.forward;

        var rend = quad.GetComponent<Renderer>();

        rend.material.shader      = shader;
        rend.material.mainTexture = texture;
        //rend.material.color = Color.red;

        return quad;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var pos = Camera.main.transform.position;

        foreach (var itm in matrix)
        {
            itm.transform.LookAt(pos);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally yes, and in this specific case where you want a quad to align with the camera makes doing so very easy.

What you want is called a "billboard shader". Here is an example from [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cg_Programming/Unity/Billboards):

```
Shader "Cg  shader for billboards" {
   Properties {
      _MainTex ("Texture Image", 2D) = "white" {}
      _ScaleX ("Scale X", Float) = 1.0
      _ScaleY ("Scale Y", Float) = 1.0
   }
   SubShader {
      Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
      ZWrite Off
      Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

      Pass {   
         CGPROGRAM

         #pragma vertex vert  
         #pragma fragment frag

         // User-specified uniforms            
         uniform sampler2D _MainTex;        
         uniform float _ScaleX;
         uniform float _ScaleY;

         struct vertexInput {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float4 tex : TEXCOORD0;
         };
         struct vertexOutput {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            float4 tex : TEXCOORD0;
         };

         vertexOutput vert(vertexInput input) 
         {
            vertexOutput output;

            output.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_P, 
              mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MV, float4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
              + float4(input.vertex.x, input.vertex.y, 0.0, 0.0)
              * float4(_ScaleX, _ScaleY, 1.0, 1.0));

            output.tex = input.tex;

            return output;
         }

         float4 frag(vertexOutput input) : COLOR
         {
            return tex2D(_MainTex, float2(input.tex.xy));   
         }

         ENDCG
      }
   }
}
```

And an explanation of how this works:

> The basic idea is to transform only the origin `( 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 )`
>    of the object
>    space to view space with the standard model-view transformation
>    `UNITY_MATRIX_MV.` (In homogeneous coordinates all points have a 1 as
>    fourth coordinate; see the discussion in Section “Vertex
>    Transformations”.) View space is just a rotated version of world space
>    with the `xy` plane parallel to
>    the view plane as discussed in Section “Vertex Transformations”. Thus,
>    this is the correct space to construct an appropriately rotated
>    billboard. We subtract the `x` `y` object coordinates (`vertex.x` and `vertex.y`) from the transformed
>    origin in view coordinates and then transform the result with the
>    projection matrix `UNITY_MATRIX_P`.

This will produce an output like this:

[image: billboarded quads]

Comment: Very cool FPS is up on 10 times! But i have a new problem https://i.imgur.com/NUBfiVW.png Is it possible to enable transparent color filtering in the same shader?

Comment: @nim happy to help. I added some changes before `Pass` that should help make it transparent. let me know if that works.

Comment: Unity says:"Use of UNITY_MATRIX_MV is detected. To transform a vertex into view space, consider using UnityObjectToViewPos for better performance." https://i.imgur.com/OgCwScN.png but all work

Comment: @nim I changed the line to try and get rid of the warning. let me know if that works

Comment: Here was compile error but i'am add after CGPROGRAM #include "UnityCG.cginc". But shader no work all hides

Comment: @nim try that, if that doesn't work it might be best to just use UNITY_MATRIX_MV :)

Comment: not work a was back to     output.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_P,
    mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MV, float4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
    + float4(input.vertex.x, input.vertex.y, 0.0, 0.0)
    * float4(_ScaleX, _ScaleY, 1.0, 1.0));