# Click to GameObject and Billboard rotate shader

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a scene with round billboards that all the time look at the camera with the shader. [This topic has details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204343/can-a-shader-rotate-shapes-to-face-camera). But I had trouble finding a click. Click detection works as long as I look at the object in its initial position. And the more the camera goes to the side of the billboard, the click detection zone is smaller. And at the end, if I see a backside, clicks do not work.

Normal detection:
[image]

Small detection:
[image]

No detection in back side:
[image]

To make these screenshots I turned off the shader that rotates the shapes. But when it turned on the behavior is the same.

My code:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        { 
            var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                Debug.Log("Click");

                if (hit.transform.name == "Quad")
                {
                    var obj = hit.collider.gameObject;

                    var texture = Resources.Load<Texture>("Textures/Ball_01");

                    var rend = obj.GetComponent<Renderer>();

                    rend.material.mainTexture = texture;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Because the shader only affects the rendering. That click detection as if they did not rotate. I do not know how to be in this situation. Looks like I need to do my Raycast implementation. It seems I need to build own tree of objects and calculate the rays manually. Or need a shader that makes Raycast. Advise something plz.

Comment: Try putting sphere colliders on the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected that shaders won't affect the collision for clicking on things. A good workaround is to use colliders that don't need to be rotated on each frame. A `SphereCollider` can work here. Just add this line where you procedurally generate the quads:

```
var col = quad.AddComponent<SphereCollider>(); 
col.center = Vector3.zero; 
col.radius = 0.2f;
```